# Como limpo a memória para evitar o sobrecarregamento?

Tags: html, python, memória, gerenciamento-de-memória

À medida que lê o HTML do site, ir apagando o que está antes. Se há algum *clear screen* no Python.

```
import mechanize

response = mechanize.urlopen("https://www.exemplo.com")
m = 0
linha = ''
if (m < 100):
  for n in response.read():
    m += 1
    linha += n
    if (n == '\n'):
      print(linha)
      linha = ''
```

Comment: resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Python é uma linguagem que gerencia sua memória automaticamente então não precisa fazer nada, a memória é liberada quando não é mais necessária. Em um caso assim o consumo é pequeno.

De qualquer forma se estiver rodando em um servidor web mesmo que não fosse automático nem faria diferença por causa da característica fugaz dos *scripts* web.

E não faria sentido limpar a tela para liberar a memória, uma coisa nada tem a ver com outra.

Comment: Eu usei esse código, mas sem o limitador 'if'. Deixei direto dessa forma print(response.read()) e simplesmente travou .. toda vez (o que aconteceu então?) ex: import mechanize response = mechanize.urlopen('www.site.com') print(response.read())

Comment: Difícil saber só com esta informação. Isso não parece muito e que esteja causando o problema.

Comment: Usei para ler o html do youtube e deu certo, mas o outro site como tinha um html muito grande, trava. Eu estou achando que é memória                                                                                                                                         ler=mechanize.urlopen"https://www.youtube.com/")                                                                          print(ler.read())